# Array excersize in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that
receives as an argument an array of numbers called 'numbers' and must return an
array containing the smallest number in the 'numbers' array at position zero and the largest number in the array 'numbers' in position 1.

````
  maxValue = Math.max(numbers)
  minValue = Math.min(numbers)
  varResult = ([minValue, maxValue]);

  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  console.log (varResult);
  } 
} ```
````

Comment: it's not clear what you're aiming to do, kindly add more details with a sample of the wanted result.

Comment: Be aware that your `for` loop is iterating over the `numbers` array, but you're displaying the `varResult` array.  Usually these two things match up. So maybe you were looking to iterate over `varResult.length` and printing the values of `varResult[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass an array to `Math.min` or `Math.max`.
You'll need to [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the numbers, like:

```
maxValue = Math.max(...numbers)
minValue = Math.min(...numbers)
```